# What is the type of a constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, pointer-to-member, name-lookup

I know constructor do not have a return type. Though I wonder, what is the type of a constructor then? Does a constructor have a type?

I tried this

```
struct A { A() {} };

template <typename A> struct foo;

int main() { foo< decltype(&A::A) > f; }
```

to get the error (gcc)

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:5:32: error: taking address of constructor 'constexpr A::A(A&&)'
    5 | int main() { foo< decltype(&A::A) > f; }
      |                                ^
prog.cc:5:35: error: template argument 1 is invalid
    5 | int main() { foo< decltype(&A::A) > f; }
      |                                   ^
```

...well, ok I cannot take the address. Also this fails:

```
int main() { foo< decltype(A::A) > f; }
```

with

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:5:32: error: decltype cannot resolve address of overloaded function
    5 | int main() { foo< decltype(A::A) > f; }
      |                                ^
[...]
```

which is probably just a very confusing error message caused by the same reason as above (cannot take adress of constructor) and I dont know what else to try..

**What is the type of a constructor?**

If it has no type, then what is it? Certainly it is not `A (member_function)()`.

**PS**: To clarify what is my confusion: [cpprefernce](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) states

> **Constructor is a special non-static member function** of a class that is
>   used to initialize objects of its class type.

And my logic goes like this: Member function have a type, constructors are special kinds of member functions, hence they should have a type. I know the reasoning is flawed, but why?

Comment: If it doesn't have a return type it doesn't have a type.

Comment: @user207421 not very convincing. An `int` does not have a return type and its type is `int`

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Because it isn't a function...

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Not very convincing. The question is about constructors, not built-in types.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I guess so, but for example cppref states "Constructor is a special non-static member function of a class that " and usually member functions do have a type

Comment: "An `int` does not have a return type and its type is `int`" what a legend

Comment: And usually 'special' indicates some exception to the general rule, and  this is one of them. Another is that you can't call it directly, and another is that you can't take its address, and yet another is that it doesn't have a name for name lookup purposes.

Comment: @SuperSimplePimpleDimple no it is not `void`. And the "bufoon" was refering to a plain `int` in a snarky comment of mine.

Comment: @SuperSimplePimpleDimple please stay classy. Calling someone a "bufoon" helps no-one and will probably get your otherwise useful comment flagged.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ok I didn't read it all, I commented too fast because it was a funny statement that "ints don't have return types and they still have types" and the guy who said "because they are not functions" - I thought he was saying that constructors are not functions.

Comment: @SuperSimplePimpleDimple just because something is implemented "low level" the same way a function is, doesn't say anything about its type. C++ types are a purely theoretical concept and shouldn't be confused with the way common C++ implementations deal with them.

Comment: @PeterT I agree with the second part of that statement, However I think I found the solution to this "problem". I will try to do something, if I don't get an error I will send the code in an answer.

Comment: @SuperSimplePimpleDimple just remember that in languages with undefined behavior (like C++) "If I don't get an error" is not a bar high enough to consider something correct.

Comment: @SuperSimplePimpleDimple PeterT is right and maybe thats your misunderstanding. The question was not aiming at understaning how the compiler implements constructors. Actually even if I knew what type a constructor is I cannot do much with that information, in that sense its a rather academical question.

Comment: @SuperSimplePimpleDimple It was me, and I wasn't.

Comment: The point of a function type is to a pointer to it. The point of a pointer is to have multiple things it can point to.

Comment: @curiousguy kind of makes sense, though it doesn't seem that thats the rule the comitee follows when introducing a type. `nullptr_t` is what comes to my mind as perfect counter example

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 C++ had many such UDT (user defined type, not user is in the end user, but not builtin types): the original STL is filled with tag types (a zero information type used to distinguish overloads); only true support for both lambda and concepts can make these bunch of tags redundant. Going back to ctors, since they don't have names, the only way to have two that took the same runtime parameter was a tag (think "complex(x,y)" vs "complex(theta,arg)") like "complex(theta,arg,polar())". In the language support lib, there is also the non throwing `new` operator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think these quotes from the C++ 17 Standard will be relevant (15.1 Constructors)

> 1 Constructors do not have names....

and

> 2 A constructor is used to initialize objects of its class type.
>   **Because constructors do not have names, they are never found during name lookup**; however an explicit type conversion using the
>   functional notation (8.5.1.3) will cause a constructor to be called to
>   initialize an object. [ Note: For initialization of objects of class
>   type see 15.6. — end note ]

and

> 10 A return statement in the body of a constructor shall not specify a
>   return value. The address of a constructor shall not be taken.

Comment: Could you also add: `A return statement in the body of a constructor shall not specify a return value.
The address of a constructor shall not be taken.` --> 11.3.4 6

Answer (score 5):

Constructors effectively do not have types.

It may be surprising that the standard doesn't say this explicitly, but since they do not have names, do not participate in name lookup, cannot have their address taken and are "functions" with no return type, it's deducible.

Comment: `Constructors effectively do not have types.` I would expect that majority of compilers interpret it as `void` return type. Functionally it is the same.

Comment: @NO_NAME good point. It may be worth to inspect how `void` functions are translated to assembly and whether constructors are similar in this case.

Comment: @NO_NAME It is possible that, in the generated code, a constructor looks a bit like a `void`-returning member function, yes. But that tells us nothing about the actual type in actual C++

Comment: @NO_NAME No. I would not only expect but *demand* that all compilers interpret it as expressed in the standard. If you can find an exception please provide it here.

Comment: @user207421 If you have a quote from the standard which says that constructors need to return void, please write an answer to the question.

Comment: @NO_NAME They don't, and it doesn't, and that is exactly the point.

Answer (score 0):

If they had a type, what could you do? Exactly nothing. This is why:

If they had one, you might be able to get the pointer to a constructor by taking its address (taking the address of an overloaded entity is unambiguous if the result is used syntactically immediately to initialize a pointer of the right type).

If they had pointers to them, what could you do? Exactly nothing.

They don't have a name. A non null pointer to constructor of `A` will always point to `&A::A`. You might as well remove the pointer boilerplate and "call the constructor" directly.